how can I substring a text
I have a column that have rows with the following pattern:
"https://abc.westeurope.kusto.windows.net"
How can I substring the cluster name which is in above example "abc" & store it in a new column using extend function?
Thanks a bunch!!

You could use the parse operator.
For example:
print input = "https://abc.westeurope.kusto.windows.net"
| parse input with "https://" output "." *


I like the split function. It is very fast and using it is like cutting a cake. In this example I cut first by .westeurope and then I cut a second time by https://.
Here's my code:
let T = datatable
(
mystring:string
)
[
"https://abc.westeurope.kusto.windows.net",
"https://def.westeurope.kusto.windows.net",
"https://xyz.westeurope.kusto.windows.net"
];
T
| extend firstsplit = split(mystring, ".westeurope")[0]
| extend clustername = split(firstsplit, "https://")[1]
| project clustername


And here's the old-fashioned grandpa way ;-)
let T = datatable
(
mystring:string
)
[
"https://abc.westeurope.kusto.windows.net",
"https://def.westeurope.kusto.windows.net",
"https://xyz.westeurope.kusto.windows.net"
];
T
| extend cut1 = substring(mystring, 8)
| extend clustername=replace_string(cut1, ".westeurope.kusto.windows.net", "")
| project clustername


Here is an additional way using regular expressions via the extract (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/kusto/query/extract-function)  function that allows you to match patterns. It is slightly more complex, but gives you more flexibility in pattern matching. For example in the following pattern I kept the region blank, which should work with other regions as well.

The first argument is the regular expression string
The second argument is the capturing group, which is the pattern enclosed in brackets that you want to return()
The 3rd argument is the string column you want to parse

Here is the query:
let T = datatable
(
mystring:string
)
[
"https://abc.westeurope.kusto.windows.net",
"https://def.westeurope.kusto.windows.net",
"https://xyz.westeurope.kusto.windows.net"
];
T
| extend clustername = extract(@'https\:\/\/([\d\w]+)\.[\w\d]+\.kusto.windows.net', 1, mystring)

